# What measures allow to distinguish points by their known distances?

Tags: geometry, analysis, metric-spaces

Let’s consider five non-colinear points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, and $E$ in a normed vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Can we somehow semi-automatically determine if the metric has a following feature—that regardless of the choice of those five points, any given distances $d(A, x)$, $d(B, x)$, …, $d(E, x)$ will either be impossible, or will distinguish *exactly one* point $x$?

Or, in other words, $d(A, x) = d(A, y) \wedge d(B, x) = d(B, y) \wedge \ldots \wedge d(E, x) = d(E, y) \Rightarrow x = y$.

Does this property have a name?

It’s obviously non-trivial—the Euclidean metric has it, while the discrete one doesn’t—but is it something that can be easily deduced from something else, or would that be a case-by-case verification process?

Comment: The Euclidean metric does not have this property. Take $x=0$ and $y=(2,0,0,0)$ with points $A=(1,1,0,0), B=(1,2,0,0), C=(1,3,0,0), D=(1,4,0,0), E=(1,5,0,0)$. The distance to $x$ and $y$ is the same for all five points...
You probably need some condition that the points are not collinear.

Comment: Thank you, I’ve edited the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "a metric space over $\mathbb R^4$"? I guess you mean "a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^4$".

Comment: A metric space with the distance function $d: \mathbb{R}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, satisfying the regular requirements for metrics—$d(x, y) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = y$, $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$, $d(x, y) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$

Comment: So the known mathematical structures on $\mathbb R^4$ are not relevant to your metric $d$? For example the vector space structures (vector sum, scalar multiplication) are irrelevant? You are just treating $\mathbb R^4$ as a set and considering any metric on that set whatsoever?

Comment: The reason I ask all of these questions is that if the answers are *yes*, *yes* and *yes*, then your question can be equivalently formulated with any set $X$ in place of $\mathbb R^4$ as long as it has the same cardinality (and so $X$ could be any one of many other well known sets of that same cardinality, such as the real number line, the power set of the natural numbers,...). My suspicion is that this is not quite what you intended.

Comment: Agreeing with @LeeMosher, not putting any additional restrictions except "a metric on the set $\mathbb{R}^4$" is far too broad to say anything useful or interesting.

Comment: You are right, I went too far in trying to make the question general, and I did intend to ask about the normed vector space at the very least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts on this question:

1. Your statement has the regrettable property of not being true without additional conditions. It is, however, true if the collection of 5 points is [affinely independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Affine_independence). I'm not finding my favorite definition in the various links, so to be definite $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in\mathbb{R}^k$ are *affinely independent* if $x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_1, \dots, x_n - x_1$ are linearly independent. This is trivial, but that is equivalent to the determinant of the matrix of those vectors being nonzero.

The reason why this is useful to note is because affine independence is a linear algebra condition. This should give you some pause to think that the property you're observing for the 2-norm may be a bit special.

2. One way to think about the behavior you're observing is the following. If you take $k+1$ affinely independent points in $\mathbb{R}^k$, each pair of points $A,B$ defines a perpendicular bisector $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^k \mid d(A,x) = d(B,x) \}$. In the case of the standard Euclidean 2-norm, you can square the distances and note that the perpendicular bisector is an algebraic hypersurface. But it is not just any algebraic hypersurface. You can easily observe directly that the quadratic terms in the equality cancel out, so that the perpendicular bisectors are linear hypersurfaces.

   This is useful, because any points which are equidistant to your fixed points must lie on the intersection of $k$ of these hypersurfaces. In other words, the intersection is defined by $k$ linear equations in $k$ variables. Affine independence implies that the corresponding system of equations is nonsingular (you can write this out, if you like). Thus there is 1 real solution because the coefficients are real.

   So one sufficient condition, I'll put it roughly, is that $k$ perpendicular bisectors of pairs of points for your distance have a unique intersection. This is up to constraining your points to be ``independent''

   The reason why this is all worth saying is that it may help you think about the next natural example to check, namely the Euclidean 4-norm instead of the Euclidean 2-norm. If you take the perpendicular bisector of $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and intersect it with the same for the pair $(0,0)$ and $(1/2,1)$, the corresponding bisectors are defined by:
   $$
   x^4 + y^4  - (x-1)^4 - y^4 = 0
   $$
   and
   $$
    x^4 + y^4 - (x-\frac{1}{2})^4 - (y-1)^4 = 0.
   $$
   They still intersect in exactly 1 real point, approximately $(1/2,0.4384)$. That lends some hope.

   Indeed, it looks like this problem has been studied somewhat extensively. I'm not an expert, so at your own peril for this, but citing from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.10702.pdf, Theorem 1, which points at some other results: If $(\mathbb{R}^n,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ is a normed vector space, then it appears every convex body has a unique circumcenter if and only if the unit ball in this norm has boundary that contains no non-degenerate line segments. In particular, if you have a set of affinely independent points, every point that is equidistant from them is a circumcenter of their convex hull. That's a pretty satisfying answer, and easy enough to check for the p-norms.